# MyBatis can not find mapper.xml

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I start a console app with **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext**, and the main class is annotated with **@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.hello"})** however. It will cause an error

> Invalid bound statement (not found):
>   com.hello.user.dao.AccountDao.remove

But,it is ok if i start app with a **FileSystemXmlApplicationContext** with application.yml like

```
mybatis:
  mapperLocations: classpath:com/hello/user/dao/mapper/*.xml, classpath:com/hello/task/dao/mapper/*.xml
```

What i should do to use **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext** with a mapper xml

Comment: Can you post the project structure of your application ?

Answer (score 0):

For AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, add the configuration file in resources folder.

Comment: After i added ImportResource to my application,it worked fine. thks!